# Expose Docker REST API on Mac Os

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to expose the http api from docker.

Reading the docs show that is possible with sockets and using the terminal I managed to use it.

But I want to use the http version, on the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#bind-docker-to-another-hostport-or-a-unix-socket) they say that I should use the dockerd with `-H` but `dockerd` is not available on macos.

I tried a lot of things but I was not able to get working.

Comment: If you succeed in this, you’ll be giving unrestricted, unauthenticated, root-level access to...on OSX, not your whole system, but merely your entire `/Users` directory, and there’s still a lot of damage a lightly-motivated attacker could do.  You really actually don’t want to do this.